# Add validation check inside text box using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to add a validation(a green check mark) inside a text box when a user meets a certain criteria.I am using JQuery to accomplish this.
I tried the below code using Fontawesome icons, but it isn't working:

```
$('#username').append('<i style="display:inline;color: #3a7d34;" class="icon-check-sign"></i>');
```

I would be very thankful if anybody can suggest me some good ideas.

**UPDATE:**

Following snippet of my html code, trying to put a check box inside the textbox

```
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username, "Username")
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-left: 5px">
                    @Html.UsernameFor(m => m.Username,
                        new
                        {
                            @class = "inputClass1 inputClass2",
                            style = "width:150px",
                            id = "username",
                            onkeyup = " return validateUsername() "

                        })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)

                </td>
            </tr>
```

Thanks,

WH

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what exactly do you mean?  What isn't working?

Comment: "it isn't working" - have you checked your JavaScript console for error logs?

Comment: Instead of appending to the textbox add a class to it that will position the validation to the end of the element.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick response
SLoW
MattHarper - I meant the check mark is not getting displayed inside the text box. No errors in console

@Press- i didn't get you, but if you meant this- $('#username').addClass("icon-check-sign")

this isn't showing the check mark either

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh75uzL/) I used Bootstrap since JSFiddle doesn't have FontAwesome.

Comment: Thanks @Press, i tried doing this-

 $('#username').html("<span class='validator-one'></span>");
            $('.validator-one').append("<i class='icon-check-sign' style='color:green;'></i>");

This is appending the check box outside the text box, not inside it..

Answer (score 1):

You can't append a icon *inside* a text input, place it beside it instead:

```js
$(function() {
$('.test').append('<i style="display:inline;color: #3a7d34;">&#10004;</i>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input><span class="test"></span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fhff4w3u/1/

Comment: i added it, somehow firefox shows me that code as greyed

Comment: And what do you mean by greyed?

Comment: its appending the below code next to textbox, but i see it as greyed, i mean its not active code...not sure if it something related to my textbox...btw, i have html helpers on that text box..
<i style="display:inline;color: #3a7d34;">✔</i>

Comment: If you post your html and all your js and a jsfiddle, I can help you

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
$('.test').append('<i style="display:inline;color: #3a7d34;">&#10004;</i>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input><span class="test"></span>
```

```js
$(function() {
$('.test')
```